# open shift can't find buildconfig

Tags: jenkins, openshift, openshift-client-tools

When I run `oc get bc`, I got "no resource found". I have no problem to get results on other commands, e.g. `oc get dc`, `oc status`. The build process was kicked off by Jenkins.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you get from `oc get all`?

Comment: Yes. I see deployemntConfigs, routes, ..., hpa. But not the buildconfigs.

Comment: You could always try increasing your log level `oc get bc --loglevel=6`. This should show you the actual API calls made. On my machine, it looks like `GET https://api.example.com:443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/my-project/buildconfigs?limit=500 200 OK in 427 milliseconds`

Comment: It's similar, but with "no resources found". GET https://<hostname>:<port>/oapi/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/buildconfigs 200 OK in 16 milliseconds
No resources found.

Comment: Interesting, your's is trying to access `oapi` versus mine at `apis/build.openshift.io`. My first guess is that your `oc` client and `openshift` server have a version mismatch. What's the output from `oc version`?

Comment: Yes. You are right. My client version is behind as just had the server upgrade. Will try to upgrade my client and see.

Comment: updated my client with same version on server. It still has the issue. GET https://hostname:port/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/buildconfigs?limit=500 200 OK in 249 milliseconds
No resources found.

Comment: And they show up fine in the Web Console? Maybe you really just don't have any `buildconfig`s in this namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on the right project (project is OpenShift parlance for a Kubernetes namespace and the oc client uses it to set your current context namespace): `oc project` will tell you which project you are currently on and `oc projects` will list all of the projects you have access to on the cluster. Use `oc project foo` to change project contexts for the oc client.

Comment: it happens to all my projects.